# Why is my ball vector retaining its components after reinit?

Tags: vector, pygame, pong

I'm writing a Pong game with Pygame and this is the code for my Ball class so far:

```
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, game, vector=Vec2D.Vec2D()):
        super(Ball, self).__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface((BALL_RADIUS*2, BALL_RADIUS*2))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.__draw_ball()

        screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
        self.area = screen.get_rect().inflate(-GAP*2, 0)

        self.vector = vector
        self.game = game
        self.reinit()

    def __draw_ball(self):
        self.image.fill(BLACK)
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK, RLEACCEL)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, WHITE, (self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery), BALL_RADIUS)

    def reinit(self):
        self.rect.centerx = self.area.centerx
        self.rect.centery = self.area.centery
        self.vector = Vec2D.Vec2D.from_magn_and_angle(BALL_SPEED, 0)

    def update(self):
        self.rect = self.calcnewpos()
        self.handle_collision()

    def calcnewpos(self):
        (dx, dy) = self.vector.get_xy()
        return self.rect.move(dx, dy)

    def handle_collision(self):
        (dx, dy) = self.vector.get_xy()

        if not self.area.contains(self.rect):
            if self.__hit_topbottom():
                dy = -dy
            elif self.__hit_leftright():
                self.game.increase_score()
                self.reinit()
        else:
            for paddle in self.hit_paddle(dx):
                if dx < 0: self.rect.left = GAP + PADDLE_WIDTH
                elif dx > 0: self.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH - (GAP + PADDLE_WIDTH)

                dx = -dx
                dy = paddle.hitpos / 4
                paddle.collided = True

        self.vector = Vec2D.Vec2D(dx, dy)

    def _hit_topbottom(self):
        return self.rect.top < 0 or self.rect.bottom > SCREEN_HEIGHT

    def _hit_leftright(self):
        return self.rect.left < self.area.left or self.rect.right > self.area.right

    def hit_paddle(self, dx):
        if dx < 0: paddle = self.game.paddles['left']
        elif dx > 0: paddle = self.game.paddles['right']

        if self.rect.colliderect(paddle.rect): return [paddle]
        else: return []
```

Well, after the player (or the AI) scores, the ball calls its **reinit** method that places the ball in the middle of the screen and resets the vector:

```
def reinit(self):
    self.rect.centerx = self.area.centerx
    self.rect.centery = self.area.centery
    self.vector = Vec2D.Vec2D.from_magn_and_angle(BALL_SPEED, 0)
```

But, somehow, the ball still maintains the vector it had before reinit was called. So when the ball gets through the left side with a vector like (-5.0 -2.0), it changes quickly in the reinit call and then change back to (-5.0, -2.0). Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: It might be that you are just setting the ball to the same vector every time. From what I see in the posted code, you arn't changing, or randomly choosing, the vector at all.

Comment: @Shade The vector changes everytime it hits the walls or one of the paddles in the **handle_collision** method. But when a point is scored, I want reinit to always set the vector to the same one `Vec2D.Vec2D.from_magn_and_angle(BALL_SPEED, 0)`

Comment: @Shade And the vector, actually, does change! It just changes back very fast to the one it had before.

Comment: Then perhaps something is still processing the vector, and 'finishes' after the vector is reset. This doesn't seem very likely, but... A few other things stand out, the `dy = paddle.hitpos / 4` might always get truncated as an integer, and dx will only ever (from what I can see), equal dx or -dx.

Comment: Ok, I see it. I'll post an answer after I type it out

Comment: @Shade Immediately after reinit is called, if you print the vector, the output is '5.0, 0.0'. However, by the time update is called, the vector already changed back to what it was before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, is in your `handle_collision` method.

The short story:
The first thing the function does, is set dx and dy to the current vector. Then it calls `reinit()`. Then, it sets them back to what the first were at the end of the function.

To fix:
Change

```
def handle_collision(self):
    (dx, dy) = self.vector.get_xy() # <-- It first sets (dx, dy) to the old vector

    if not self.area.contains(self.rect):
        if self.__hit_topbottom():
            ...
        elif self.__hit_leftright():
            ...  # <-- here is where the reinit gets called, which changes the vector to new values.
    else:
        for paddle in self.hit_paddle(dx):
            ...

    self.vector = Vec2D.Vec2D(dx, dy)  # <-- Then the vector gets changed again, to the OLD vector saved above in (dx, dy)
```

To

```
def handle_collision(self):
    (dx, dy) = self.vector.get_xy()

    if not self.area.contains(self.rect):
        if self.__hit_topbottom():
            ...
        elif self.__hit_leftright():
            ...
            return  # <-- With the return here, the parsing never gets to change it back
    else:
        for paddle in self.hit_paddle(dx):
            ...

    self.vector = Vec2D.Vec2D(dx, dy)
```

This will prevent the vector getting set back to what it was, while still setting it when it needs to be.

Comment: Sorry, it worked! But i still don't get it. Could you explain further why was this happening?

Comment: I got it now! Thanks, Shade.